# Error 400 on Comparison and Input Code in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to do a Macro in VBA for comparison and inputs.

The context is, based on the average calculated from rows 2 to 25 in a particular column ranging from Columns B to AR, if the value of the particular row is below the average, it will show the corresponding value of Column A in row 25 of each respective row

For example, the average value for Column B from Cells B2 to B25 is 2.20, and Cells B2, B4, B6, B9, B10, B12, B14, B16, B18, B20, B22 and B24 are below the average of 2.20. The corresponding value for Column A is 1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23 respectively to the Cells in Column B, then Row 27 (Cell B27) will show the input as "1,3,5,8,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23". For the remaining cells not mentioned earlier, it will be shown in Row 28 (Cell B28) as "2,4,6,7,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24".

Image is shown here [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLp2F.jpg)

```
Sub CompareAndInput()
    Dim avg As Double
    Dim belowAvg As String
    Dim aboveAvg As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 2 To 44 'Loop through columns B to AR
        avg = Cells(30, i).Value
        belowAvg = ""
        aboveAvg = ""
        
        'Loop through rows 2 to 25 and compare to average
        For j = 2 To 25
            If Cells(j, i) < avg Then
                belowAvg = belowAvg & Cells(j, 1) & ","
            Else
                aboveAvg = aboveAvg & Cells(j, 1) & ","
            End If
        Next j
        
        'Remove trailing comma
        belowAvg = Left(belowAvg, Len(belowAvg) - 1)
        aboveAvg = Left(aboveAvg, Len(aboveAvg) - 1)
        
        'Input results in rows 27 and 28
        Cells(27, i) = belowAvg
        Cells(28, i) = aboveAvg
    Next i
End Sub
```

This is my code that received an error 400. There is conditional formatting already in place as shown in the image, yellow for below the average value and green for above the average value. Please help

Answer (score 1):

### Identify Below and Above Averages By Column

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PopulateAverageRows()

    Const SRC_RANGE As String = "B2:AR25"
    Const AVG_ROW As Long = 30
    Const DST_ROW As Long = 27
    Const DELIMITER As String = ","
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim drg As Range, sData, aData, srCount As Long, cCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(SRC_RANGE)
        sData = .Value
        aData = .EntireColumn.Rows(AVG_ROW).Value
        srCount = .Rows.Count
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        Set drg = .EntireColumn.Rows(DST_ROW).Resize(2)
    End With
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To 2, 1 To cCount)
    Dim dLen As Long: dLen = Len(DELIMITER)

    Dim Value, sr As Long, c As Long
    Dim Average As Double, Below As String, Above As String
    
    For c = 1 To cCount
        Value = aData(1, c)
        If VarType(Value) = vbDouble Then
            Average = Value
            For sr = 1 To srCount
                Value = sData(sr, c)
                If VarType(Value) = vbDouble Then
                    If Value < Average Then
                        Below = Below & sr & DELIMITER
                    Else
                        Above = Above & sr & DELIMITER
                    End If
                End If
            Next sr
            If Len(Below) > 0 Then
                dData(1, c) = Left(Below, Len(Below) - dLen)
                Below = ""
            End If
            If Len(Above) > 0 Then
                dData(2, c) = Left(Above, Len(Above) - dLen)
                Above = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    drg.ClearContents
    drg.Value = dData

    MsgBox "Average rows populated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The error 400 indicates that there is an issue with the syntax or structure of your VBA code.

There are a couple of changes needed in your code so try this updated VBA code let me know if it works for you-

```html
Sub CompareAndInput()
    Dim avg As Double
    Dim belowAvg As String
    Dim aboveAvg As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    For i = 2 To 44 'Loop through columns B to AR
        avg = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(25, i)))
        belowAvg = ""
        aboveAvg = ""
        
        'Loop through rows 2 to 25 and compare to average
        For j = 2 To 25
            If Cells(j, i).Value < avg Then
                belowAvg = belowAvg & Cells(j, 1).Value & ","
            Else
                aboveAvg = aboveAvg & Cells(j, 1).Value & ","
            End If
        Next j
        
        'Remove trailing comma
        belowAvg = Left(belowAvg, Len(belowAvg) - 1)
        aboveAvg = Left(aboveAvg, Len(aboveAvg) - 1)
        
        'Input results in rows 27 and 28
        Cells(27, i).Value = belowAvg
        Cells(28, i).Value = aboveAvg
    Next i
End Sub
```